# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: book.isbn when parsing and inserting csv data into database

Tags: python, mysql, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm fairly new to the whole flask/sqlalchemy frameworks so I'd like to ask some help in figuring out what's wrong with my flask application. As far as I can see I've done the primary to foregin key relationships as they should be which is a one to many from Book to Reviews. Please any sort of help would be appreciated thanks in advance! I've inserted my code below for further reference.

main.py

```
with open('books.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    for row in reader:
        book = Book(isbn=row['ISBN'],title=row['Book-Title'], author=row['Book-Author'],
        publication_year=row['Year-Of-Publication'], publisher=row['Publisher'])
        db.session.add(book)
        db.session.commit()


print('database initialized!')
```

models.py

```
class Review(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)      
  text=db.Column(db.String)
  rating=db.Column(db.Integer)     
  book=db.Column(db.String,db.ForeignKey("book.isbn"))

  def toDict(self):
    return {
      "id": self.id,
      "text": self.text,
      "rating": self.rating,
      "isbn": self.isbn
    }

class Book(db.Model):
  isbn=db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
  title=db.Column(db.String)
  author=db.Column(db.String)
  publication_year=db.Column(db.String)
  publisher=db.Column(db.String)
  reviews = db.relationship('Review', backref='book_review',lazy=True, cascade="all, delete-orphan")
  
  def toDict(self):
    return {
      "isbn": self.isbn,
      "title": self.title,
      "author": self.author,
      "publication_year": self.publication_year,
      "reviews": self.reviews
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique constraint failure when inserting into a table happens when you try to insert a row which has a value from a column with `UNIQUE` attribute conflicts with the existing data which has the identical value. To resolve the issue,if you are inserting into an empty table, you can edit the CSV file and use `find` or other options to locate the duplicate values. And if the table has existing data, I would suggest creating a temporary table without defining PK/UNIQUE for the said column. Then populate data from both sources. Next, run a statement like this to find the duplicate values:

```
select problematic_column, count(problematic_column) ct from temporary_table 
group by problematic_column having ct>1 ;
```